# file_exists() can't find file when hosted online

Tags: php, file

The code works perfectly on my local host (by xampp) but this problem started when I moved it to online host.

I have a driver php code that naviagte to the page if it finds it in folder `pages` or `techPosts` the problem is that I can load some files by `file_exists()` but can't load the others?

The driver code is located in `index.php` in the root of my host in `/public_html`

```php
<?php

include_once "config.php";
include "functions.php";

$db = db_connection();

$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'home';

include_once './views/_header.php';

if (file_exists("./pages/{$page}.php")) { //for the normal pages
    include "./pages/{$page}.php";
} elseif (file_exists("./techPosts/{$page}.php")) { //for the story of posts
    include "./techPosts/{$page}.php";
} else {
    include './pages/404.php';
}
include_once "./views/_footer.php";

db_close($db);
```

and here is the folder tree for my files

```
public_html/
    index.php
    pages/
        Forall_Posts.php
        home.php
        A.php
        B.php
        C.php
        D.php
        E.php
        F.php
    techPosts/
        test.php
```

in `home.php` it loads the whole content of my page by this

```php
<?php require_once './pages/B.php' ?>

<?php require_once './pages/C.php'; ?>

<div id="aboutSection">
    <hr class="page-break" data-aos="zoom-out">
    <?php require_once './pages/D.php'; ?>
</div>

<hr class="page-break" data-aos="zoom-out">
<?php require_once './pages/E.php'; ?>

<hr class="page-break" data-aos="zoom-out">
<?php require_once './pages/F.php'; ?>
```

## What I tested

**1.Reference by absolute path using `__DIR__`**

in `index.php`

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__."/pages/{$page}.php")) { //for the normal pages
    include __DIR__."/pages/{$page}.php";
```

same, it can't load the page.

**2.Change ternary operator to land on `Forall_Posts` instead of `home`**

```php
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'Forall_Posts';
```

it lands on it, so it means that the file can be found.

#### Solution but not best one

Add a specific if condition just for `Forall_Posts.php`

```php
if (file_exists("./pages/{$page}.php")) { //for the normal pages
    debug_to_console("First if condition");
    include "./pages/{$page}.php";
} elseif (file_exists("./pages/Forall_Posts.php")) { //only to this page
    debug_to_console("Second if condition");
    include "./pages/Forall_Posts.php";
} elseif (file_exists("./techPosts/{$page}.php")) { //for the story of posts
    include "./techPosts/{$page}.php";
} else {
    include './pages/404.php';
}
```

It can find `Forall_Posts.php` now, but when I try with `A.php` it goes to `Forall_Posts.php` and I have output that says `"Second if condition"`.

At this point I don't understand anything, why it didn't go to the else statemenet and just show the `404.php` page but go to the specific if condition and skip the first one?

Comment: if you are using the absolute path you have a couple of errors in there. The constant is `__DIR__` rather than `___DIR__` (which has 3  and 2 underscores ) and you then lose the `.` before `./pages/`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thanks for pointing it out, I changed it but still can't find the page

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing reference  one of the

```php
<?php require_once './pages/E.php'; ?>
```

to

````php
<?php require_once './pages/Forall_Posts.php.php'; ?>```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you do not need this "../" or "./" when you want to fetch content from a folder that is NOT from the "back" directory, let's consider the index.php and you want to include E.php you can simply write include_once("pages/E.php");

Comment: changed to 

```lang-php

if (file_exists("pages/{$page}.php")) { //for the normal pages
    include_once "pages/{$page}.php";

``` 
but still can't find it

Comment: maybe you have a problem with the variable $page, echo it and see if it prints the same thing as you sent with the GET p parameter. because you wrote something wrong see, actually isset() function returns true or false and the $page variable becomes boolean if you send p Parameter but if you don't send and if the p parameter is null in the condition you wrote the $page will be a string that has the default file name you gave. so please correct that and response back

Comment: the output is the correct name for page, and the if condition is working fine, problem is in the ```file_exists()``` function when trying to find files in this specific folder, it works fine in ```techPosts/

Comment: yes because there's not a file named true!